# ¿Cómo encriptar un hipervínculo en PHP?

Tags: php

¿Cómo podria encriptar el siguiente hipervínculo, que mando a una persona para recuperar su correo?:

```
<a href="http://mipagina.com/recovery.php?email='.$_POST["email"].'">Restablecer Contraseña</a>
```

Lo que pasa es que he visto que en hipervínculo me aparece el correo, y al modificarlo podrían hacer cambios que no están permitidos.

Quisiera hacerlo simple con PHP MD5 pero no se donde colocarlo o como sería.

Comment: MD5 es un algortimo de HASH no de encriptación

Comment: Aparte de eso, lo que necesitas es generar un GUID, almacenarlo en la base de datos como una solicitud de recuperación de correo y utilizar únicamente este GUID en el link. El correo, nombre de usuario etc, nunca deben estar en texto plano o encriptados en el link, sino que deben ser recuperados de la base de datos únicamente por lado servidor

Comment: Pero entonces no habria una forma de harlo con md5 lo que quiero? se que en teoria no es correcto pero empezaria por esto y ya luego mejorarlo...

Comment: Con mi primer comentario me refería a que el término utilizado es incorrecto. MD5 es una función no reversible, es decir, una vez generado el HASH no es posible obtener la información original a partir del HASH. No es un algortimo de encriptación por lo que no podrías obtener el email a partir del HASH. Podrías utilizar como ya mencioné un algoritmo de encriptación pero de todas maneras, es mucho más fácil y adecuado generar un simple GUID, guardando la información relevante a la solicitud sólo en la BD sin transmitirla

Comment: Pff la verdad no entiendo como pudo hacer esto, la verdad soy algo nuevo, supongo que tendre que crear otro campo en la bd, pero igual con la guia que me diste ya me ayudo un poco. Gracias amigo

Comment: Ya entendi y analice la idea amigo, es practicamente lo que hago pero con un GUID, osea no hay falla, creo que esta facil.
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta... ¿Qué quiere decir "encriptar un hipervínculo"? Quieres encriptar la session HTTP (HTTPS)? Quieres encriptar algunos parámetros del URL?  O quizás ¿solo quieres utilizar un [HMAC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)?

Answer (score 3):

Hacerlo como indicas no es conveniente. Tal como te han dicho en los comentarios deberías:

- Generar un token. Este token puede ser en md5, sha1, o incluso un UUID asociado con el usuario.
- Enviarle en un enlace ese token y mediante el mismo verificar los datos del usuario.

Comment: Si gracias al final lo realice de esta manera, no entendia la logica pero ya quedo!

Answer (score 1):

Primero verifica que ese *email* existe... Si existe, puede hacerle un `hash` al ID y construir tu url asi:

---

```
$hash = md5($idUsuario);

<a href="http://mipagina.com/recovery.php?email='.$_POST["email"].'&key='.$hash.'">Restablecer Contraseña</a>
```

---

Luego, en la pagina de recovory, puedes hacer la consulta por el email y el hash del id.

Como ejemplo inicial esto te puede ayudar.

*hash = puedes usar cualquier hash como `md5`, `md6`, `sha1`, ect..